# window.parent.postMessage() not working after a bunch of redirects

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, oauth, slack

My web app opens a window in order to do OAuth2 via a third party service. Once the login is done, the 3rd party service redirects the window to my server, which renders the following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><script>
window.parent.postMessage({someData:123},"*");

</script></head><body></body></html>
```

The redirect_uri has the same domain as the page opening the original popup. For some reason however, the postMessage is not going through. However, when instead of the 3rd party login page I open the redirect_uri directly, the postMessage works just fine.

Just in case it matters, the 3rd party service here happens to be Slack.

Comment: Check your console for potential error messages.

Comment: Is the OAuth popup closing itsself and telling the main window to redirect itsself? Or is the OAuth popup loading the redirect into it's own window that was opened by the parent and you end up with the original window before the popup and a seperate window with the redirection?

Comment: No errors, also getting no errors when I try postMessage w the console.

Comment: The OAuth popup window is redirecting the popup I've created

Comment: Tried setting https://  mydomain.com/ instead of "*", which did not help but setting it to https:// mydomaintypoed.com/ throws an error and complains it wont match the receipient, so apparently it is somehow still listening to it, it's just that the msg wont go through...

Comment: Apparently you get that error on any page...

Comment: Same error here. Does anyone get the solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.opener.postMessage instead of window.parent.postMessage